# Обработка JSON в Perl

Tags: массивы, json, perl

получаю вот такие данные

[{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:38:43Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:38:43Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"ну еще одна.попытка.на этот раз.должна быть удачной :)"},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:58Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:58Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"еще один тест.многострочного.комментария."},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:58Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:58Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"еще один тест.многострочного.комментария."},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:57Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:57Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"еще один тест.многострочного.комментария."},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:20:00Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:20:00Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"Тестовый коммент.sна несколько.sстрок.s"},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:19:56Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:19:56Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"Тестовый коммент.sна несколько.sстрок.s"},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:16:47Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:16:47Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"строка1строка2строка3"},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T10:53:43Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T10:53:43Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"ыфыаывадлвыоадывоадывоаыв"},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T10:17:38Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T10:17:38Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"Тестовый коммент от разраба"},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-14T10:13:11Z","postedAt":"2017-09-14T10:13:11Z","creator":"Подрядная Организация","message":"test"},{"updatedAt":"2017-09-13T10:44:55Z","postedAt":"2017-09-13T10:44:55Z","creator":"Нечаев Денис Анатольевич","message":"Тестовый комментарий
Коллеги (ЦУМ), прошу тикет не закрывать."}]

JSON Formatter показывает:

```
[  
   {  
      "updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:38:43Z",
      "postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:38:43Z",
      "creator":"Подрядная Организация",
      "message":"ну еще одна.попытка.на этот раз.должна быть удачной :)"
   },
  {  
      "updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:58Z",
      "postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:58Z",
      "creator":"Подрядная Организация",
      "message":"еще один тест.многострочного.комментария."
   },
   {  
      "updatedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:58Z",
      "postedAt":"2017-09-14T11:26:58Z",
      "creator":"Подрядная Организация",
      "message":"еще один тест.многострочного.комментария."
   },
```

как правильно на перле обрабатывать такой массив?

Comment: пробовали use JSON; decode_json ? (http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/JSON-2.94/lib/JSON.pm)

Comment: Если это действительно JSON, то вам сюда (сюрприз!): https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON (или ::XS). Но не напрягайтесь, следующая попытка погуглить или посмотреть в документации вам точно что-то надорвёт.